# "Expression preceding parantheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type" error in IAR EW

Tags: c, macros, embedded, iar

I am developing a project in IAR Embedded Workbench and I keep getting an error from function-like macros. The error and snippet of my code that causes the error is below.
Build Log:

```
    Error[Pe109]: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type   
 
    Error[Pe018]: expected a ")"
```

Code: this is from main.c file

```
  __UPDATE_SAFETY_VAR(dw_STL_dev_var, 0uL);
```

Definition of the macro: from a different header file.

```
#define __UPDATE_SAFETY_VAR(x, value)  x = value; \
x##_inv = (__typeof__(x))(~value)
```

I added the header file as preprocessor in "Options->C/C++ Compiler".
I included the header file in main.c.
I tried adjusting the parantheses but nothing worked.

I looked the error from the internet but I could not find a useful solution. Every suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You could try to run the preprocessor only to see what is the expanded result of your code. I am not sure how to do that with IAR compiler.

Comment: Why do you need to add that header file to your project settings? Every C file should include headers that are needed.

Comment: It could be a problem that is not in the line you showed us but in the previous lines. Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error.

Comment: Whenever troubleshooting _any_ C problem, the declarations of all variables involved is always extremely relevant.

Comment: Does IAR support `__typeof__`? Is there any sound reason why you can't just cast to `(uint32_t)` and then let that result get converted by assignment to `x##_inv`?

Comment: It is in any event an unsafe macro definition.  `value` and `x` should be parenthesised throughout in case either are passed as expressions where the operator precedence and order of evaluation may be an issue.

Comment: More context required (i.e. surrounding or complete code and complete compiler diagnostics).  Also IAR EWB for what target?

Comment: `__typeof__` is a GNU extension to C.  I have looked at a number IAR of compiler manuals, and none I have found support `__typeof__`.  IAR EWB is not a compiler; your question is ambiguous is you do not specific the compiler/target architecture, but likely this extension is simply not supported.  If that is the case then this is an X-Y problem.  Better ask how to do what you want this macro to do than to ask why this macro does not work.

Comment: From the IAR C/C++ Development Guide (for Arm, version [9.30](https://netstorage.iar.com/FileStore/STANDARD/001/001/665/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf#page=207)), section "Relaxations to the C Standard": "The non-standard operator `typeof` is supported when IAR extensions are enabled, as a way of referring to the type of an expression. The syntax is like that of `sizeof`, but it behaves semantically like a type name defined with `typedef`. This is an extension found in the GNU C compiler". However, it is unclear if the feature was implemented for earlier versions or other targets.

Answer (score 3):

As Clifford has identified in the comments, the problem is most likely that you are using the non-standard `__typeof__` and the compiler does not support it.

However, looking at the code, there is probably no real need for typeof.  Assuming that `x` and `x_inv` have the same type then the cast is a no-op anyway.  The value must be converted to carry out the assignment.

There other faults with these few lines of code:

Firstly, a macro that contains an assignment must always be enclosed in `do{}while(0)`:

```
#define __UPDATE_SAFETY_VAR(x, value)  do{ \
  x = value; \
  x##_inv = (__typeof__(x))(~value); \
}while(0)
```

Removing the (probably redundant) cast gives:

```
#define __UPDATE_SAFETY_VAR(x, value)  do{ \
  x = value; \
  x##_inv = ~value; \
}while(0)
```

Finally, why do you need to keep separate copies of `x` and `x_inv`?  Why not keep a single copy and then take its inverse when you actually need it?

Comment: "a macro that contains an assignment must always be enclosed in do{}while(0)" Yes, no, maybe... it depends on how you intend to use the code and what your coding style is. If your code is some form of public or commerical library to be used by unknown strangers, then yes definitely use `do while(0)`. If your code is part of a high quality code base/coding standard which doesn't allow control or loop statements that don't come with `{}`, then using `do while(0)` is harmful. See [What is do { } while(0) in macros and should we use it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/279576)

Comment: It's an interesting point that there could be a very unusual corner case where do-while macros would let buggy code compile when it would otherwise error, but I think there are better static analysis tools to reliably and automatically detect such buggy code than to change coding style to rely on this coincidence causing a confusing syntax error.

Comment: An `if - else` statement containing a macro call is not a "very unusual corner case". Best practice is of course to avoid multi-line function-like macros to begin with. In this case the macro should have been `#define __UPDATE_SAFETY_VAR(x, value) ( (x) = (value), x##_inv = ~(value) )` (This is about the only valid use of the comma operator that exists.)

Comment: An if-else missing the braces when your coding standard requires them to always be present is an unusual corner case, and there are better ways of detecting it.  You already said if your coding standard doesn't require that then do-while wrapping macros is good.  I agree it's a bit hacky as its not what do-while was intended for, but has become standard enough that most people recognize without confusion and do it automatically.